# Telegram Bot Class not found

Tags: laravel, bots, telegram

When I run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

I get the error:

> Class 'Telegram\Bot\Laravel\TelegramServiceProvider' not found

what is wrong?

Comment: are you using a package ? and what version of Laravel are you using ?

Comment: @PrestonGarvey22 hi, i'm using Telegram Bot SDK on laravel 5.5

Comment: That strange, Laravel 5.5 should have discover the package automatically. Can you point me to the package repo link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
composer dump-autoload
composer update
```

than run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```